# How to migrate MVVMCross based Xamarin.android project into Intune managed one

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, intune

I have a android project running smoothly, it uses MVVMCross at its core.

The problem came when I was asked manage the app protection policies with Intune.

Now Intune is forcing me to use their managed activity and all other managed namespaces provided by Intune SDK.

In that case, how I can proceed with it?

I tried changing activities base class to Intune's one, in hope to use general things provided by Mvvmcross, such as IOC, dependency injections.

I customised App startup as Intune wants that means there will not be any setup/app.cs class calls involvement.

So I launch Splash activity -> and it launches MainActivity, in MainActivity I am manually injecting all the Dependencies which I require.

Because all these syntaxes are throwing exception under Intune managed activities 
example: `Mvx.RegisterType<IDeviceInformation, DeviceInformation>();`

Above throws exception.

How do I proceed with this migration keeping MVVMcross basic functionality intact?

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of solutions to that matter that I can think of.

If you only need the DI you can add another DI manager package and handle it from there which will be simpler than configuring Mvx to do that only.

If you need other capabilities of Mvx then you will have to do what Mvx does in its base classes and implement them taking into consideration setting the appropiate interfaces to your base classes.

In Android, in order to get the Setup and Activities working you'll have to:

- Register your setup in your android Application file as done [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Views/MvxAndroidApplication.cs#L49)

  `this.RegisterSetupType<TMvxAndroidSetup>();`
- Implement your own base activity that takes into consideration the implementation of `IMvxEventSourceActivity` such as [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Views/Base/MvxEventSourceActivity.cs) and also the `MvxActivity` like [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Views/MvxActivity.cs) in order to have the events and the data context / viewmodel handling

```cs
[Register("mvvmcross.platforms.android.views.base.MvxEventSourceActivity")]
public abstract class MvxEventSourceActivity
        : Activity, IMvxEventSourceActivity
{
    protected MvxEventSourceActivity()
    {
    }

    protected MvxEventSourceActivity(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        CreateWillBeCalled.Raise(this, bundle);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        CreateCalled.Raise(this, bundle);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        DestroyCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        NewIntentCalled.Raise(this, intent);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        ResumeCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        PauseCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        StartCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        RestartCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StopCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnStop();
    }

    public override void StartActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
    {
        StartActivityForResultCalled.Raise(this, new MvxStartActivityForResultParameters(intent, requestCode));
        base.StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        ActivityResultCalled.Raise(this, new MvxActivityResultParameters(requestCode, resultCode, data));
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        SaveInstanceStateCalled.Raise(this, outState);
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            DisposeCalled.Raise(this);
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public event EventHandler DisposeCalled;

    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> CreateWillBeCalled;

    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> CreateCalled;

    public event EventHandler DestroyCalled;

    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Intent>> NewIntentCalled;

    public event EventHandler ResumeCalled;

    public event EventHandler PauseCalled;

    public event EventHandler StartCalled;

    public event EventHandler RestartCalled;

    public event EventHandler StopCalled;

    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> SaveInstanceStateCalled;

    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxStartActivityForResultParameters>> StartActivityForResultCalled;

    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxActivityResultParameters>> ActivityResultCalled;
}
```

```cs
[Register("mvvmcross.platforms.android.views.MvxActivity")]
public abstract class MvxActivity
    : MvxEventSourceActivity
    , IMvxAndroidView
{
    protected View _view;

    protected MvxActivity(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    protected MvxActivity()
    {
        BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(this, this);
        this.AddEventListeners();
    }

    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }

    public IMvxViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return DataContext as IMvxViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
            OnViewModelSet();
        }
    }

    public void MvxInternalStartActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
    {
        StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }

    public override void SetContentView(int layoutResId)
    {
        _view = this.BindingInflate(layoutResId, null);

        SetContentView(_view);
    }

    protected virtual void OnViewModelSet()
    {
    }

    protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
    {
        if (this is IMvxSetupMonitor)
        {
            // Do not attach our inflater to splash screens.
            base.AttachBaseContext(@base);
            return;
        }
        base.AttachBaseContext(MvxContextWrapper.Wrap(@base, this));
    }

    private readonly List<WeakReference<Fragment>> _fragList = new List<WeakReference<Fragment>>();

    public override void OnAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        base.OnAttachFragment(fragment);
        _fragList.Add(new WeakReference<Fragment>(fragment));
    }

    public List<Fragment> Fragments
    {
        get
        {
            var fragments = new List<Fragment>();
            foreach (var weakReference in _fragList)
            {
                if (weakReference.TryGetTarget(out Fragment f))
                {
                    if (f.IsVisible)
                        fragments.Add(f);
                }
            }

            return fragments;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        ViewModel?.ViewCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        ViewModel?.ViewDestroy(IsFinishing);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        ViewModel?.ViewAppearing();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        ViewModel?.ViewAppeared();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        ViewModel?.ViewDisappearing();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        ViewModel?.ViewDisappeared();
    }
}

public abstract class MvxActivity<TViewModel>
    : MvxActivity
    , IMvxAndroidView<TViewModel> where TViewModel : class, IMvxViewModel
{
    public new TViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (TViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }
}
```

- Also you'll have to implement your own splash activity like [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Views/MvxSplashScreenActivity.cs) which implements the `IMvxSetupMonitor` and is the one who ends up calling the setup [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Views/MvxSplashScreenActivity.cs#L54) by calling `MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);` and initializing a monitor.

```cs
[Register("mvvmcross.platforms.android.views.MvxSplashScreenActivity")]
public abstract class MvxSplashScreenActivity
    : MvxActivity, IMvxSetupMonitor
{
    protected const int NoContent = 0;

    private readonly int _resourceId;

    private Bundle _bundle;

    public new MvxNullViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return base.ViewModel as MvxNullViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    protected MvxSplashScreenActivity(int resourceId = NoContent)
    {
        RegisterSetup();
        _resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    protected MvxSplashScreenActivity(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void RequestWindowFeatures()
    {
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        RequestWindowFeatures();

        _bundle = bundle;

        var setup = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);
        setup.InitializeAndMonitor(this);

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        if (_resourceId != NoContent)
        {
            // Set our view from the "splash" layout resource
            // Be careful to use non-binding inflation
            var content = LayoutInflater.Inflate(_resourceId, null);
            SetContentView(content);
        }
    }

    private bool _isResumed;

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _isResumed = true;
        var setup = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);
        setup.InitializeAndMonitor(this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        _isResumed = false;
        var setup = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);
        setup.CancelMonitor(this);
        base.OnPause();
    }

    public virtual async Task InitializationComplete()
    {
        if (!_isResumed)
            return;

        await RunAppStartAsync(_bundle);
    }

    protected virtual async Task RunAppStartAsync(Bundle bundle)
    {
        if (Mvx.IoCProvider.TryResolve(out IMvxAppStart startup))
        {
            if(!startup.IsStarted)
            {
                await startup.StartAsync(GetAppStartHint(bundle));
            }
            else
            {
                Finish();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual object GetAppStartHint(object hint = null)
    {
        return hint;
    }

    protected virtual void RegisterSetup()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class MvxSplashScreenActivity<TMvxAndroidSetup, TApplication> : MvxSplashScreenActivity
        where TMvxAndroidSetup : MvxAndroidSetup<TApplication>, new()
        where TApplication : class, IMvxApplication, new()
{
    protected MvxSplashScreenActivity(int resourceId = NoContent) : base(resourceId)
    {
    }

    protected override void RegisterSetup()
    {
        this.RegisterSetupType<TMvxAndroidSetup>();
    }
}
```

This will cover the basics I think.

Hope it helps you to get you to the right direction